What's the difference between orthographically doubled vowels and long vowels ("uu" vs "ū")?
Some Latin words and declensions have an orthographic "uu", contrasting with orthographically single long u "ū" (-uus in mortuus vs -ūs in spīritūs for example). A similar situation exists for "ii"/"ī". I'm wondering how to distinguish the pronunciation of these two forms and what the impact of the distinction is for meter, syllabification, etc. I've seen that in some sources positing phonetically lax [ʊ] for short "u", "uu" is analyzed as [u.ʊ] (Wiktionary gives [ˈmɔr.tu.ʊs] for mortuus), but I'm curious how these forms are dealt with in reconstructions which reject the existence of lax [ʊ] and propose a purely quantitative distinction between short and long "u". Likewise for "i". As a native English speaker, phonemic vowel length being foreign to me, it's a little hard for me to wrap my head around how the distinction between [u.u] and [uː] or [i.i] and [iː] could be perceptibly articulated orally.

Related

Though I don't think this is a duplicate, since it's specifically asking about the reconstructions that have only a quantity distinction (no quality distinction), and the other one isn't.

It does interfere with Latin prosody and meter if you pronounce double vowels as long vowels.
One distinction that should be clearly audible to an English speaker is the effect on which syllable is accented: spīritūs is accented on the first syllable whereas exiguus is accented on the second syllable.
Phonetically, long vowels were presumably pronounced by elongating a single vocalic gesture. In contrast, it seems simplest to assume that the articulation of double vowels, as in exiguus, involved two vocalic gestures, not separated by a complete pause, but by a period of less intense noise. For comparison, in careful speech in Japanese there can be a contrast between long vowels and double vowel sequences: double vowels are pronounced with a dip in phonetic intensity that can be seen on a spectrogram. Here's the chart provided by Timothy J. Vance's The Sounds of Japanese (page 59) showing the phonetic difference in Japanese between long /oː/ (on top) and double /oo/ (on bottom):

As a practical matter, it doesn't interfere with Latin prosody if you insert some kind of consonantal sound between the vowels to help keep them separate. As I mentioned in an answer to How was "VV" pronounced?, if you do use a consonant here, the historical development of Latin and its descendants supports using a glide [w] rather than a glottal stop [ʔ], but neither of these would introduce real ambiguity, since Latin doesn't have /ʔ/ as a phoneme and it doesn't have a significant phonemic contrast between word-internal /u.u/ and /u.wu/.

I'm glad you found those images, because this comes up so often I was close to making my own. Also worth noting that nihil did become nīl when h went away, though, so even the Romans struggled with V.V.

@Cairnarvon: There are some specific cases where two vowels were contracted to one. Other examples include deest pronounced /deːst/, vehementer pronounced /weːmenter/, or cooperiant becoming cōperiant in Lucretius (though /koo/ seems to have been used by other poets). It's not a universally applied rule, though.
